# GameCenter using Adobe Gaming SDK 1.3 crashes on Live Environment

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, game-center

I have a game made with Adobe Air 4.0 for iOS.  Using the ANE for the Game Center works just fine in the Sandbox, but when submitting my app for approval it got rejected because it crashes when it tries to send the score.

These are the logs they sent me:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s147/sh/72eb6e2e-5542-42a6-b35b-75a782c086b3/4d2ae1e67c2c4206034697108fdd7d32

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s147/sh/9f57e242-baac-45a1-a16e-f7eda0129c90/04ded99f7645c0a627450913714ed892

After receiving the notification, I quickly tested my game and for some reason it didn't logged me in the Game Center Sandbox and yeah, it crashed. After testing again it logged me back to the Sandbox and everything was fine.

So, exists any way to fix this besides buying the Milkman ANE? 
And, how to test the game outside of the Sandbox? because Apple documentation states that only apps with Distribution build can use the Live Environment, but I clearly saw that at least for one game I wasn't in the Sandbox (haven't being able to reproduce this).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue , although not (yet) rejected by apple. It seems like it works fine if it is in sandbox mode and not really when out of the sandbox mode. I used the ANE provided by adobe gaming sdk ( I think they are the same) and it does the same. I found this issue out as whenever I am out of internet I am not in sandbox mode.

I think we have to remove Game Center Score Board features for now.

Edit:After some trials I found that my crashes are related to the fact that I have not specify the leader board name (So default scoreboard). It works as intended after giving the function the leader board ID

Comment: At the end I have to switch to Milkman's ANE. It works like a charm.